# Contact Form 7 - on link click fill text field

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form, contact-form-7

I'm trying to make a job posting with Contact Form 7.

There are a lot of different jobs and what I would like to do is to make somekind of a script when you click on a button in one job posting then in form should field with job title be filled. I have no clue how to even do this or is it possible.

Has anyone tried this before? If anyone did, how did you made it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the form on the same page or in the pop-up?

Comment: There is just one form with 3 steps, as you can post it without looking into job offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension Plugin which allows adding the dynamic values

Comment: I think that fills all my needs. I'm gonna try it out. Thank you very much.